# Normally its easy to solving mean and covariance of Bernoulli Distribution but how we do when its Bernoulli Distribution vector in below Questions?

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution, mixture-distribution

Maybe it's so easy to solve but I confused, Could anyone explain to me how can I solve these 2 questions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: (i) requires only applying the definitions; you can find (literally) thousands of examples here on CV.  That leaves (ii), which is a question about moments--it's not special to Bernoulli distributions.  That question is answered by the duplicate.  For more examples, please visit our [threads on moments and mixtures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixture+moment).

Comment: What kind of definitions are them? Could you help?

Comment: And also the link above that you send me for duplication not solve the ii) problem, its different btw!